# Loading a XML file and injecting data into a table and return it as a navigation/tableview

Tags: c#, iphone, cocoa

So here's the situation: I have a friend who wants me to make an app for his comic website, he wishes for me to set it up so the comics appear in a tab (navigation and tablelist/view). Im not sure what the best method for his XML file is, i do know of the xml code on how do it, but unfortunately, i do not know nor have ever used the code for it.

so im sorta lost, this is the file: http://hoshen.controlshiftblack.com/HoshenFeed.xml

And does anyone have any simple to use suggestions for using XML in an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are saveral ways to get the job done, you can use an xml library and make a parser for your xml feed like

NSXML 
http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/09/nsxml-on-iphone.html

or libxml 
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/04/simplifying-libxml.html

Also there are third party parsers that allow you to use Objective-c objects, one widely used is 
GData
http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/RayWenderlich/~3/YuSy-Gey1sg/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

If that's not enough, ask your friend to send you JSON data instead and use a JSON library for iPhone

http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/using-objective-c-json-to-do-translations-in-an-ios-app/